# How can I search for objects in a stream?

Tags: java, search, filter, enums, stream

I have a .csv file like this:

```
11/08/2019;14:00;Newcastle;Arsenal;0;1;A;M Atkinson;1;3;0;0
```

After read, the lines are parsed.

Stored them in MatchStatistics ArrayList:

```
List<MatchStatistics> data;
```

Every field before ";" is an object.

Necessary object for us is Team(Arsenal -> item3) and MatchResult(A -> item6).

Team and MatchResult are enums.

My job is to find the count of the specified Team and the specified MatchResult within a processor class.

I tried this but not working so well:

```
public long getSpecifiedResult(List<MatchStatistics> data, Team team, MatchResult result) {
 return data.stream()
  .filter(item -> item.equals(team))
  .filter(item -> item.equals(result))
  .count();
}
```

Thank you for Your help! :)

Comment: Can you provide the Team class, MatchStatistics class, and MatchResult class.  It seems that you are compare a MatchStatistics object with Team object and a MatchResult object.  I assume you override equals(Object obj) of MatchStatistics to handle both type of objects.

Comment: Of course. Sorry for the styleing.
https://codeshare.io/j0j4BM

Comment: Please edit your question and add the other classes’ code to it directly.  A codeshare.io page will eventually disappear, making your question useless to future readers.